# Subtract string lists in Oracle SQL

Tags: string, oracle, oracle12c

I have two tables with the user in their services. Due to the size of the `user_services` table, transforming into rows ins't really practical (most users have 100s of services). How could I subtract one list from another?

```
user_services (aprox 2mi recrods)
USER    SERVICES    
Rick    1,3,2,66,19
Jerry   1,2,19

serices_remove
serv_rm
1,16,19,32

output
USER    SERVICES
Rick    3,2,66
Jerry   2
```

I'm using Oracle 12c.

Comment: Well *relational* approach would be to have a child service table with a single key and a *remove* table containg the service keys to be deleted. You may transform to this scenario by splitting your *csv* list, there are lot of examples on this site.

Comment: thanks. will reconsider splitting into rows.

Answer (score 2):

I would still suggest to transform your comma separated value into rows. Manipulating these CSV columns on both ends of the query is tedious, error-prone, and will not perform well. With this kind of set up, you will not be able to use indexes.

On the other hand, consider :

- a lookup tables where each record stores a user id and a (single) associated service
- an exclusion table where each record represents a service to remove

On large dataset, index scans are a magnitude faster than full scans : with a relevant index, only 25 comparisons are needed to locate the relevant record out of 10 million rows (log2 of 10 M is 23.5).

This will also allow you to simplify your query as :

```
SELECT l.*
FROM lookup_table l
LEFT JOIN exclusion_table e ON e.service = l.service
WHERE e.service IS NULL
```

Or :

```
SELECT l.* 
FROM lookup_table l
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM exclusion_table e WHERE e.service = l.service
)
```

If aggregation per user is needed, it can be handled using a SQL function (or better yet in the presentation layer).

Tip : here is a query that you could use to initialize your new table ; it splits the CSV column into new rows :

```
select distinct usr, trim(regexp_substr(serv, '[^,]+', 1, level)) serv
from (SELECT usr, services serv FROM user_services) t
connect by instr(serv, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
```

See **[this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=01c4d154580f4320550cc55a9bdcf1ec)**

```
 with user_services as (
     select 'Rick' usr, '1,3,2,66,19' services from dual
     union select 'Jerry', '1,2,19' from dual
 )
 select distinct usr, trim(regexp_substr(serv, '[^,]+', 1, level)) serv
 from (SELECT usr, services serv FROM user_services) t
 connect by instr(serv, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
      order by 1,2
```

```
 USR   | SERV
 :---- | :---
 Jerry | 1

 Jerry | 19

 Jerry | 2

 Rick  | 1

 Rick  | 19

 Rick  | 2

 Rick  | 3

 Rick  | 66
```